# print or show full output in python

Tags: python, pandas, printing

im searching for columns with NA, for that i use this code:

```
train.isna().sum()

Id                 0
MSSubClass         0
MSZoning           0
LotFrontage      259
LotArea            0
                ... 
MoSold             0
YrSold             0
SaleType           0
SaleCondition      0
SalePrice          0
Length: 81, dtype: int64time: 29.5 ms (started: 2021-11-08 10:28:26 +00:00)
```

i like the solution but i need to see all the columns, not the short version

any idea how to print the full version or a more proper way to search for column with NA?
the solution was:
pd.set_option('max_rows', None)
print(train.isna().sum())

Comment: use `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)`  once then you can see all results

Answer (score 0):

`pd.set_option('max_columns', None)` before your `train.isna().sum()` command.

See: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-show-all-columns-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe-c49d4507fcf

Comment: pd.set_option('max_rows', None)  
print(train.isna().sum())